# Drag/Drop SVG element between SVG containers

Tags: javascript, html, svg, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to clone SVG element in one SVG container and drag&drop it into another SVG container?
I have SVGs setup like this:

```
<svg> -source container
 <g><!-- some elements --></g>
</svg>
<svg> -destinatin container
</svg>
```

I would like the ability to drag/drop elements from the source container into the destination container. Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b143fo8c/2/).
I added drag&drop from [here](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/draggable-svg-element) but this only work inside one SVG container.

Comment: You'd have to delete the object in the original container and append it to the new container.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't want to delete it, just clone it. But is it possible, after detaching it from the source container, to drag/drop and attach it to destination container?

Comment: Once you have a reference you can use appendChild to append it anywhere you want.

Comment: Are you asking about the cloning-then-appending process?  Or are you asking about how to show an svg element whilst it is being dragged between the two SVGs on the page.?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I am talking about cloning-then-appending process between two SVGs

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is simple.  Just do a `removeChild()` to remove the element from the first SVG. Then do an `appendChild()` to add it to the second SVG.

If the element is not a direct child of the `<svg>` element, then you will need to call `removeChild()` on the parent group of the element.  Ie. the group element if it is in a group.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {

  var rect = document.getElementById("rect");
  var fromSVG = rect.ownerSVGElement;

  var toId = (fromSVG.id === "source") ? "dest" : "source";
  var toSVG = document.getElementById(toId);

  fromSVG.removeChild(rect);
  toSVG.appendChild(rect);
});
```

```css
#source {
  background-color: #ffeeee;
}

#dest {
  background-color: #eeffee;
}
```

```html
<svg id="source">
  <rect id="rect" x="100" y="50" width="50" height="40" fill="red"/>
</svg>

<svg id="dest">
</svg>

<br/>

<button id="btn">Click me to move rectangle</button>
```